# How to Adjust the width of navigation drawer in android studio

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I downloaded a navigation template, and I want to adjust the width of navigation. I've tried different methods but I think nothing suited. How can I solve my problem? I can't adjust the width of the navigation drawer.

This is my code for the NavigationalDrawerFragment.java

```
package com.example.user.navigationkamo;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.res.Configuration;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
 import android.graphics.Rect;
 import android.graphics.RectF;
 import android.graphics.Shader;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.util.TypedValue;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

/**
* Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
* See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
* design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
*/
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
    NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
    adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    return view;
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}



public boolean isDrawerOpen() {

    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
}

public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
    return mDrawerLayout;
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    selectItem(position);
}

public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
    List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Driver Details", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_driver)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Track Me", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_track)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Contact", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Report Driver", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_report)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Call for Emergency", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_call)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Rate Taxi", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_rate)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Favorites", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Top Drivers", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_top)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem("Security Tips", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_security)));
    return items;
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
 */
public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {


            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
    ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
}

public void openDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public void closeDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void setUserData(String user, String email, Bitmap avatar) {
    ImageView avatarContainer = (ImageView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail)).setText(email);
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername)).setText(user);
    avatarContainer.setImageDrawable(new RoundImage(avatar));
}

public View getGoogleDrawer() {
    return mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.googleDrawer);
}

public static class RoundImage extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Change the width in the navigation view directly.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_actual_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_actual_home_drawer" />
```

For e.g I have changed the `width` to `350dp` directly in my layout file as above.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look in the Activity's *layout*-file were you firstly assign the *NavigationDrawer*. Beside a few other information you should find a section looking like this

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.myapplication.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

The tag `android:layout_width` defines your drawer's width and it's linked to the *dimensions*-file. If you look there (cmd/ctrl + click) you can look up or redefine this value:

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

<!-- Per the design guidelines, navigation drawers should be between 240dp and 320dp:
     https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html -->
<dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">240dp</dimen>
```

Of course you can set the width directly in the *layout*-file too.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I want the width of Navigation View equals 90% the width of device's screen. So I change the Navigation View's width programmatically.

```
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val widthOfNav = (Screen.width) * 0.9
navView.layoutParams.width = widthOfNav.toInt()
navView.requestLayout()
```

and here is the way you get the screen's width

```
object Screen {
    val width: Int
        get() = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels

    val height: Int
        get() = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
}
```

Answer (score 3):

only you have to change just  `android:layout_width="200dp"`
adjust '200dp'.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_customer_home_page"
        app:itemIconTint="#8c000000"
        app:itemTextColor="#e6000000"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_customer_home_page_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the values\dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- Per the design guidelines, navigation drawers should be between   240dp and 320dp:
     https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html -->`enter code here
<dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">250dp</dimen>
<dimen name="toolbar_elevation">4dp</dimen>
```

Comment: You can now change the <dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">250dp</dimen> 

Change the 250dp to your desired width